Does this hadith (Aisha and the 11 housewives) prove that Music is allowed in islam? And how does it relate to other hadith?
the two hadith in question are ( Aisha and the 11 housewives)
->Sahih al-Bukhari 5189 Book 67, Hadith 123 &
->Sahih Muslim 2448a Book 44, Hadith 135 &
->Ash-Shama'il Al-Muhammadiyah 252  Book 38, Hadith 1:
'A'isha reported that (one day) there sat together eleven women making an explicit promise amongst themselves that they would conceal nothing about their spouses.
...
The tenth one said:
My husband is Malik, and how fine Malik is, much above appreciation and praise (of mine). He has many folds of his camel, more in number than the pastures for them. When they (the camels) hear the sound of music/lute/tambourine/flute ( الْمِزْهَرِ) they become sure that they are going to be slaughtered.
قَالَتِ الْعَاشِرَةُ‏:‏ زَوْجِي مَالِكٌ، وَمَا مَالِكٌ مَالِكٌ خَيْرٌ مِنْ ذَلِكِ، لَهُ إِبِلٌ كَثِيرَاتُ الْمَبَارِكِ، قَلِيلاتُ الْمَسَارِحِ، إِذَا سَمِعْنَ صَوْتَ الْمِزْهَرِ ، أَيْقَنَّ أَنَّهُنَّ هَوَالِكُ
....
So basically, my logic tells me that the people of Mecca/Medina apparently listened to the sound of the flute/lute/tambourine before they would slaughter camels and have dinner festivals (and this practice happened during the jahil, ignorance, time peroid and while the prophet was sill alive). Mizhar (الْمِزْهَرِ) means lute or a string instrument like a guitar or oud but can also mean tambourine or flute (مِزْمرِ) was mentioned in another narration. There is not mention of silk, wine, or sexual intercourse in the hadith above just only the musical insturment and feast gathering (since all hadith on the prohibition of musical interments always include prostitutes and alcohol). Because the 5590 hadith in bukhari mentions after the death of prophet Muhammad (pbuh) people will legalize the four things (silk, wine, fornication, musical instruments).
But the musical insturments is happening during the time of the prophethood according the the above hadith, so how do we interpert ma'azif ( وَالْمَعَازِفَ ) if apparently wind and string insturments are supposedly haram, but here string instruments are being used when slaughtering camels?
The prophet pbuh did not condemn festivals/dinner gatherings with music involved in authentic hadith. And the hadith above is authentic in both Bukhari and Muslim unlinke the 5590 hadith in bukahri which is only authentic is bukhari collection (and some scholars criticized it's authenticity). neither Aisha nor prophet muhammad (pbuh) critized the tenth wife or abu malik for playing the mizhar (الْمِزْهَرِ) so are insturments haram?
And what does this mean for the alleged consensus that all companions of the prophet pbuh believed that music was sinful. Does this hadith cancel the consensus notion?

As you said, it happened during the period of jahiliyyah so that answers the question. The proceeding hadith talks about the prohibition of music so it includes what happened during such events as well, as it did not specify otherwise or set exceptions.

the 5590 Hadith promises the people who mix silk, wine, fornication, and music will be turned into monkies and pigs. So did Musa and the tenth wife ever turn into apes and swines for their music use? The question is does the 5590 Hadith mention haram for the four items individually or when you put all four together? because the top Hadith seems to me that it shows music is allowed if you remove  of the obvious haram elements of silk, wine, and fornication.

Your logic here is falty. Because there are people who mix all 4 of those and still don't get turned into pigs or monkeys. The hadith is not interpreted that way and doesn't warrant this transformation for everyone who does this.

Could it be metaphorically turned into monkies or pigs their personality (behaving like animals essentially)? Or maybe the change will happen on the day of judgement.

The point that I'm trying to argue is that Aisha is narrating the hadith, she can't be a child (meaning she's married) here nor is this occurring after the first 300 years of Islam. This hadith mostly likely takes place while the prophet is still alive. And the people of Mecca and Median are using string instruments while they have family/guest gatherings. The 5590 hadith is predicting the future. So the the prophet said music will be halal in the future, but here the people of Arabia are engaging in music , why didn't he condemned it in an authentic hadith while he's alive .

Okay, so let's get one thing straight: Islam prohibited things in stages. Some things were made prohibited at an earlier stage, others were made so much later. Do you know that wine was made prohibited much later and in Medinah? There was a time when madinah's street smelled like wine because everyone threw out all the wine they owned once they heard of the prohibiton. Just because the Prophet PBUH is alive during an event, it does not mean that he necessarily condones or condemns it.

In that case, that sounds like mubah (neither haram nor halal). There is not authentic hadith where the prophet destroyed musical instruments the same way he did for alcohol. Here is an analogy: the president says I will make electric cars legal in 5 years. Okay, show me in the consitituion where you original prohibited it? Since everyhting is permissible by deafult. I can't find the original source of the prohibition, but I can find a instance where the people around you engaged in electrical cars and used them freely in your area and you didn't enforce the law on them or punish them?

Again, at one point, even the sahaba drank alcohol freely the same way they enjoyed music freely and the Prophet PBUH did not prohibit them until much later in madinah when the revelation for it arrived after Omar radiallahu'anhu said alcohol should not be allowed. Before that, it was just as normal as drinking milk.
Secondly, your example is flawed. In your example, the president is intending to eventually make electric cars, while in the case of the Prophet PBUH, the content is that people will wrongfully consider music (alongside adultery, alcohol, and silk clothing) halal.

He is prophesizing their error.

Please check the hadith contents mentioned here: https://seekersguidance.org/answers/hadith/are-the-hadiths-regarding-music-authentic-or-not/

". I can't find the original source of the prohibition" When a source states that people will consider X thing incorrectly permissible, it also implicitly says that it is impermissible. The source makes mention that it will be an error of people to consider it permissible, so it must mean that it also intends to state it as impermissible. I don't think it can get clearer than that, really.

"Could it be metaphorically turned into monkies or pigs their personality (behaving like animals essentially)? Or maybe the change will happen on the day of judgment. – " No, the scholars do not interpret it both of those ways. The transformations will happen near the day of judgement, and before it, but it is not warranted for everyone who commits a combination of those acts the same way drinking alcohol doesn't warrant complete inability to be able to go to jannah (as the hadith says about the one who drinks alcohol to not be able to even smell the scent of jannah). It just doesn't apply to-

everyone but will happen to people eventually.

Good point, but you assumed music must be originally haram. the original arabic of the hadith in 5590 does not include the words "mistakly" or "wrongfully"  or "incorreclty" that would be your scholars interpretation of the hadith. You imposed that understanding becase you are convinced that music is haram. The same website tells of the difference of opinion on music (https://seekersguidance.org/answers/halal-and-haram/is-listening-to-music-haram/).

it's was a nice conversation, but we should end it here before it gets unproductive.

The difference of opinion is a valid one based on the specific instruments. The original arabic does not use that word but makes mention of a punishment upon those who do deem those acts permissible and indulge in them. That implicitly conveys prohibiton. Why would Allah punish those who do something permissible? I think I have made my point crystal clear. Perhaps if you read this entire conversation from top to bottom with a clear mind, it should make sense as a whole.

the scholars that I follow say that if you put all four elements together, like the example of a nightclub or inappropriate concert, the punishment/prohibition applies there.

There is no such valid opinion that it's halal with conditions, it simply doesn't exist. The only difference of opinions is regarding what instruments are allowed. Some scholars give a broader list of instruments, while some only limit to the daff. But there's no scholar who says that all musical instruments are permissible regardless or regardful of the conditions.

I believe both opinions that music is halal and haram are valid in Islam. you follow the majority opinion that music is haram and I follow the minority opinion that i's halal with conditions. Thanks for the info.

No problem, it was a productive conversation nonetheless.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Please add a link to the hadith in question enumeration of hadith books was invented by editors not by the authors therefore a reference number only identifies a specific edition. I suppose what you are referring to is hadith Umm Zara' Some questions about the hadith of Umm Zara'
